# Action called once by socket but handled in reducer twice

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, redux

I have been having a problem where an action called in one of my components causes the reducer two handle the event twice, one event directly after another with the exact same payload as previous.

Here is the output of the console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWmft.png

Here is the code the action follows:

```
componentWillMount() {
  console.log('component is mounting')
  this.props.secureSocket.on('RECEIVE_CHAT', (data) => {
    console.log('got a socket message')
    this.props.receiveChat(data)
  })
}
```

^ this catches the socket's action from the api and dispatches the action accordingly, only firing one time

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    sendChat,
    receiveChat
  }, dispatch)
}
```

^ this is how the prop is binded to dispatch

```
export function receiveChat(object) {
  console.log('action called')
  return {
    type: RECEIVE_CHAT,
    payload: object
  }
}
```

^ this is the action being dispatched

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, { type, payload }) {
  switch (type) {
    ...
    case RECEIVE_CHAT:
      console.log('RECEIVED CHAT')
      return update(state, {
        messages: {
          $push: [payload]
        }
      })
    ...
  }
}
```

^ this is how the action is being reduced, but it is being called twice

**EDIT**
Here is the code that fires on componentWillUnmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log('unmounting')
  this.props.secureSocket.off('RECEIVE_CHAT')
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough to go off from what you've given.

Comment: You might want to try hosting a repro repo or something

Comment: What does `update` do in your reducer?

Comment: The update is just immutability-helper module provided by Facebook. I know the update function isn't causing it because I've changed the way the object is being pushed into the state multiple times with no change.

Comment: @JoeClay sorry forgot to notify

Comment: If you've got an answer to add, **add an answer**!  You're explicitly encouraged to do so here.  Avoid adding "solved" or embedding your answer in your question, though.  I've edited it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was my own wrongdoing in a redux middleware.

I used `forEach` on an object in the middleware, where I would then call `return next(action)` if the parameters were not met for the middleware, which would effectively create a new action being called on each forEach recursion.

Thank you to everyone who contributed an answer.